# Meaning of sqlstate in activity monitor table?

Tags: db2, monitoring, db2-luw

I'm investigating phenomena for a transaction and created an activity monitor.

```
db2 "create event monitor act_stmt for activities write to table manualstart"
db2 "set event monitor act_stmt state = 1"
```

A certain query is used to check whether the phenomena I'm looking for has appeared and indeed it does. However, when I look at the sqlstate for this query is says '02000' which I interpret as "Not found", at the same time it says ROWS_RETURNED = 1

I would have expected sqlstate to be '00000' for the query that returned a row. Am I missing something here?

```
db2 "select sqlstate, sqlcode, rows_returned 
     from ACTIVITY_ACT_STMT x 
     join ACTIVITYSTMT_ACT_STMT y 
         using (appl_id, uow_id, activity_id) 
     where stmt_text = 'SELECT 1 from EVENT.ADMISSION_EVENT 
                        where admission_event_id = ?' 
      and ROWS_RETURNED = 1"

SQLSTATE SQLCODE     ROWS_RETURNED       
-------- ----------- --------------------
02000            100                    1
```

As far as I can tell, the only thing that distinguishes a query that returned a row from one that does not is ROWS_RETURNED. Am I overlooking something or is that the way to tell if a query returned rows or not?

I tried to simplify the scenario by asking two questions and got a similar, but the opposite result (both queries have sqlstate '00000'):

```
db2 "select tabname from syscat.tables where 1=0 fetch first 1 rows only"
db2 "select tabname from syscat.tables where 1=1 fetch first 1 rows only"

db2 "select sqlstate, sqlcode, rows_returned, substr(stmt_text,30,20) 
     from ACTIVITY_ACT_STMT x 
     join ACTIVITYSTMT_ACT_STMT y 
         using (appl_id, uow_id, activity_id) 
     where stmt_text like 'select tabname from syscat.tables 
                           where 1=% fetch first 1 rows only'"

SQLSTATE SQLCODE     ROWS_RETURNED        4                   
-------- ----------- -------------------- --------------------
00000              0                    1 bles where 1=1 fetch
00000              0                    0 bles where 1=0 fetch


]$ db2level
DB21085I  This instance or install (instance name, where applicable: 
"db2inst1") uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL11055" with level 
identifier "0606010F".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v11.5.5.0", "s2011011400", 
"DYN2011011400AMD64", 
and Fix Pack "0".
Product is installed at "/opt/ibm/db2/V11.5".
```

Comment: Neither `sqlcode` nor `sqlstate` are listed among the [recorded monitor elements](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.mon.doc/doc/r0007595.html) -- are they taken from/do they match the [`sqlca` element](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.mon.doc/doc/monitor-elements-s.html#r0001355)?

Comment: Yes, I tried to map the columns in the table ( ACTIVITY_ACT_STMT ) against https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.mon.doc/doc/r0007595.html#r0007595__Event_activityLogicalDataGroupdeta-142 and figured that the sqlca would correspond against SQLCABC, SQLCAID, SQLCODE, etc columns in the table. I may have jumped to conclusions, and hoping that someone could shine some light on what `sqlstate` means in this table